# How to run and debug AzerothCore using CLion

Tags: clion, azerothcore

[CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/?from=AzerothCore) is a powerful multi-platform IDE that allows to run and debug C++ applications.

I tried to use it with an [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) core project.

It is smart enough to detect all the processes:

[image: AzerothCore processes in CLion]

Mostly I'm interested in running the `worldserver`.

However when I try to run or debug it, it correctly compile and runs but it will look for the `worldserver.conf.dist` configuration file in the directory `/usr/local/etc/`, giving error because that file is not there.

I would like to manually specify the path of such configuration file, as well as passing other CMake parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by opening **File** -> **Settings** and looking for "CMake" under **"Build, Execution, Deployment"**.

From that window I could pass my CMake options, which in my case where:

```
-G "Unix Makefiles" -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=static -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Werror" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Werror" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/the/main/server/dir
```

The `/path/to/the/main/server/dir` is where my `etc`, `data`, etc... folders are and the `worldserver.config.dist` is inside this `etc` folder. So doing this everything worked fine.

I also changed the "Build options" to better use my processor, passing `-j 10`.

[image: Configure CMake on AzerothCore with CLion]

---

For macOS users, you'll probably need to add these CMake options as well:

```
-DMYSQL_ADD_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
-DMYSQL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib
-DREADLINE_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/readline/include
-DREADLINE_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib
-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
-DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib
-DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```