# Set CMake Ninja build output same format as Unix Makefiles

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, ninja, azerothcore

In [my C++ app](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) I use CLion as IDE and I have set it up like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206799/how-to-run-and-debug-azerothcore-using-clion).

I noticed that the `Generator` (under `Settings->Build->CMake`) has been changed to [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

[image: CLion cmake build conf]

And the build output is no longer nice and descriptive (and warnings are no longer shown):

[image: Ninja build output of AzerothCore]

With the `Unix Makefiles` generator, it used to output like this:

[image: Unix Makefiles build output of AzerothCore]

Which is much nicer, showing more information and warnings.

Is there a way I can set the Ninja build output format the same as the one of Unix Makefiles?

Comment: Yes, Ninja absolutely shows warnings as they appear. It just doesn't scroll the output when they don't, keeping the terminal free of clutter, so warnings and errors are *all* you see. And it's *significantly* faster. (At least on the command line.)

Comment: @DevSolar ok but how to show the output in a different format?

Comment: I never bothered to find out, as I find the Ninja output to be superior (albeit admittedly less show-off-ish). If I had that answer I would have written it. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> ... (and warnings are no longer shown) ... showing more information and warnings ...

Ninja **absolutely does** still show warnings when they appear.

> Is there a way I can set the Ninja build output format *the same* as the one of Unix Makefiles?

**No.** However, the best you can do (short of patching Ninja) is this:

Add `--verbose` to the "Build options:" line entry item in that same settings dialog from your first picture to get line-by-line outputs in Ninja.